# Реализация структуры данных дек на кольцевом буфере

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Имеется следующая задача:

Гоша реализовал структуру данных Дек, максимальный размер которого определяется заданным числом. Методы push_back(x), push_front(x), pop_back(), pop_front() работали корректно. Но, если в деке было много элементов, программа работала очень долго. Дело в том, что не все операции выполнялись за O(1). Помогите Гоше! Напишите эффективную реализацию.

**Внимание: при реализации используйте кольцевой буфер.**

Формат ввода
В первой строке записано количество команд n — целое число, не превосходящее 100000. Во второй строке записано число m — максимальный размер дека. Он не превосходит 50000. В следующих n строках записана одна из команд:

- push_back(value) – добавить элемент в конец дека. Если в деке уже
  находится максимальное число элементов, вывести «error».
- push_front(value) – добавить элемент в начало дека. Если в деке уже
  находится максимальное число элементов, вывести «error».
- pop_front()    – вывести первый элемент дека и удалить его. Если дек
  был пуст, то    вывести «error».
- pop_back() – вывести последний элемент дека и удалить его. Если
  дек был пуст, то вывести «error».

value — целое число, по модулю не превосходящее 1000.

Мое попытка решения:

```
class Deque:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.queue = [None] * n
        self.max_n = n
        self.head_push = 0
        self.head_pop = 0
        self.tail_push = 0
        self.tail_pop = 0
        self.size = 0

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.size == 0

    def sizes(self):
        print(self.size)

    def push_front(self, x):
        if self.size != self.max_n:
            self.queue[self.head_push] = x
            self.head_pop = self.head_push
            self.head_push = (self.head_push - 1) % self.max_n
            self.size += 1

        else:
            print('error')

    def push_back(self, x):
        if self.size != self.max_n:
            self.queue[self.tail_push] = x
            self.tail_pop = self.tail_push
            self.tail_push = (self.tail_push + 1) % self.max_n
            self.size += 1
        else:
            print('error')

    def pop_front(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            print('error')
        else:
            x = self.queue[self.head_pop]
            self.queue[self.head_pop] = None
            self.head_push = self.head_pop
            self.head_pop = (self.head_pop + 1) % self.max_n
            self.size -= 1
            print(x)

    def pop_back(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            print('error')
        else:
            x = self.queue[self.tail_pop]
            print(x)
            self.queue[self.tail_pop] = None
            self.tail_push = self.tail_pop
            self.tail_pop = (self.tail_pop - 1) % self.max_n
            self.size -= 1

n = int(input())
deque_size = int(input())
q = Deque(deque_size)
for i in range(n):
    ll = input().split()
    if ll[0] == 'pop_front':
        q.pop_front()
    elif ll[0] == 'pop_back':
        q.pop_back()
    elif ll[0] == 'push_front':
        q.push_front(ll[1])
    else:
        q.push_back(ll[1])
```

Здесь

- head_push - это индекс, по которому новый элемент вставляется в
  начало
- tail_push - это индекс, по которому новый элемент вставляется в конец
- head_pop - это индекс первого элемента, он удаляется функцией pop_front
- tail_pop - это индекс последнего элемента, он удаляется функцией pop_tail

Код падает на тесте:

```
9
8
push_back -977
pop_back
pop_back
push_front -86
pop_back
push_back 81
pop_front
pop_back
pop_back
```

Но я не могу понять в чем дело, где ошибка.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy прошу прощения, это рудимент моих попыток исправить код. Сейчас должно выглядеть нормально. Именно этот код не работает.

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю - а зачем вам две пары указателей на `head` и `tail`? Пара должна быть только одна. Скорее всего у вас проблема именно с синхронизацией этих двух ваших пар.

Comment: Хотя так то логика с виду правильная. А тест не сообщает, на какой именно команде он падает и что не так?

Answer (score 0):

```
from typing import List


class Deque:
    """Класс двусторонней очереди."""
    def __init__(self, max_length) -> None:
        self._elements: List.Any = [None] * max_length
        self._max_length: int = max_length
        self._head: int = -1
        self._tail: int = 0
        self._size: int = 0


    def push_front(self, value) -> None:
        """Добавляет элемент в начало очереди."""
        if self._size >= self._max_length:
            raise IndexError('Дег заполнен, добавление невозможно!')
        self._elements[self._head] = value
        self._size += 1
        self._head = self.__get_new_index__(self._head, -1)

    def push_back(self, value) -> None:
        """Добавляет элемент в конец очереди."""
        if self._size >= self._max_length:
            raise IndexError('Дег заполнен, добавление невозможно!')
        self._elements[self._tail] = value
        self._size += 1
        self._tail = self.__get_new_index__(self._tail, 1)

    def pop_front(self):
        """Удаляет элемент из начала очереди и возвращает его."""
        if self.is_empty():
            raise IOError('error')
        self._head = self.__get_new_index__(self._head, 1)
        result = self._elements[self._head]
        self._size -= 1
        return result

    def pop_back(self):
        """Удаляет элемент из конца очереди и возвращает его."""
        if self.is_empty():
            raise IOError('error')
        self._tail = self.__get_new_index__(self._tail, -1)
        result = self._elements[self._tail]
        self._size -= 1
        return result


    def __get_new_index__(self, index, new):
        """Получение нового указателя, после добавления/удаления элемента."""
        return (index + new) % self._max_length


    def is_empty(self) -> bool:
        """Возвращает булево значение.
        True - если очередь пуста. Иначе False."""
        return self._size == 0


    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join(map(str, self._elements))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    """Основная логика программы."""
    amount_commands = int(input())
    max_length = int(input())
    deque = Deque(max_length)
    for _ in range(amount_commands):
        command, *values = input().split()
        try:
            call_method = getattr(deque, command)
            if values:
                call_method(*values)
            else:
                print(call_method(*values))
        except AttributeError:
            raise AttributeError(f'Значение"{command}" не используется!')
        except (ValueError, IndexError, IOError) as error:
            print('error')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]